# Display only selected term from content type in Views

Tags: views

maybe this is duplicate but I cant find solution and answer for this one, maybe its so basic buy I need little  help about.

I have content type with:
 1. Title
 2. Body
 3. Category
(Category field is Vocabulary check box with two taxonomy terms called 
 1. Yes
 2. No

So I have contents some are with selected yes and some one are selected with no, I want to create a view and display only with the selected (Yes) contents. Any idea how should I do it. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your Views,

Add *filter criteria* > *Has taxonomy term* > *apply*

**Vocabulary**: *your vocabulary in question* > *Apply*

**Is one of**: *Yes* > *Reduce duplicates* > *Apply*

Save your Views.

HTH

Comment: I knew it! I knew I am missing something there and is so basic. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view with show ***Content*** of type your ***content type*** and continue and edit
2. Add a filter under ***Filter criteria*** select ***content : field*** (ie a taxonomy term reference field)
3. Select terms from vocabulary having yes value with operator ***Is one of***

**Result** : Content listed with terms tagged with yes